# Получить историю счета с сервера MetaTrader C#

Tags: c#

Есть ли способ получить историю счёта с сервера Metatrader из C# приложения без терминала?

Известные данные:

- Адрес сервера (IP, port)
- Login (Номер счета)
- Password

Comment: В чем вопрос и в чём проблема?

Comment: @Monk Вопрос можно ли подключиться к серверу MT напрямую и получить от него историю по конкретному счету (зная номер счета и его пароль)